# Improve a list of if

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

So a page where I do a search based on a bunch of filters but all of them are optionals.
I have my controller here:

```
def distribution
    begin
      @service_request = ServiceRequest.find(params[:id])
      @claimed, @unclaimed = 0, 0
      @conditions = ContractorSearchConditions.new()
      @conditions.zipcode = @service_request.zipcode.to_s
      @conditions.search_terms = params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:keywords].present? ? params[:filters][:keywords] : 'general'
      params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:proximity].present? ? @conditions.mile_radius = params[:filters][:proximity] :
      params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:results].present? ? @conditions.page_size = params[:filters][:results] :
      @conditions.page = 1
      @contractors = Contractor.search(@conditions)
      @contractors.each do |contractor|
        if contractor.uid == 26
          @unclaimed = @unclaimed+ 1
        else
          @claimed = @claimed+ 1
        end
      end
    rescue => e
      flash[:error] = "#{e}"
      redirect_to :action => :edit
    end
  end
```

And my struct here:

```
class ContractorSearchConditions < Struct.new(:search_terms, :state, :zipcode, :lat, :lng, :mile_radius, :account_type, :page, :page_size)

  #convert zipcode into lat, lon, and state
  def prepare
    zip = ZipCode.find(zipcode)
    self.state.nil? ? self.state = zip.state : self.state = self.state
    self.lat.nil? ? self.lat = zip.latitude.to_f : self.lat = self.lat.to_f
    self.lng.nil? ? self.lng = zip.longitude.to_f : self.lng = self.lng.to_f
    self.mile_radius.nil? ? self.mile_radius = 15 : self.mile_radius = self.mile_radius.to_i
    self.page_size.nil? ? self.page_size = 50 : self.page_size = self.page_size.to_i
    self.page.nil? ? self.page = 1 : self.page = self.page
  end


end
```

and

The thing is that my struct will be used in different controller across the app so I went to check the params and set default ones.

But I'm quite not happy with the all my line of if.

Any idea how I could make it better ?

**Edit:**
New distribution method:

```
    begin
      @service_request = ServiceRequest.find(params[:id])
      if params[:filters].nil?
        params[:filters] =  Hash.new
        params[:filters] = {:mile_radius => 15, :page_size => 50, :search_terms => 'general', :score => 100}
     end
     @conditions = ContractorSearchConditions.new(params[:filters])
     @conditions.zipcode = @service_request.zipcode.to_s
     @contractors = Contractor.search(@conditions)
     @claimed, @unclaimed = 0, 0
     @contractors.each do |contractor|
      if contractor.uid == 26
        @unclaimed = @unclaimed+ 1
      else
        @claimed = @claimed+ 1
      end
    rescue => e
      flash[:error] = "#{e}"
      redirect_to :action => :edit
    end
  end
```

and here is the view:

```
<fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <%= f.label :keywords, "Keywords", :class => 'control-label' %>    
          <%= f.input :keywords, :required => true, :label => false, :as => :string, :input_html => {:class => 'form-control', :maxlength => 255, :value => params[:filters][:keywords]}, :no_wrapper => true %>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <%= f.label :results, "# Results", :class => 'control-label' %>    
          <%= f.input :results, :required => true, :label => false, :input_html => {:class => 'form-control', :value => params[:filters][:results]}, :no_wrapper => true, :as => :number %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <%= f.label :proximity, "Proximity", :class => 'control-label' %>    
          <%= f.input :proximity, :required => true, :label => false, :input_html => {:class => 'form-control', :value => params[:filters][:proximity]}, :no_wrapper => true, :as => :number %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

and my struct:

```
class ContractorSearchConditions < Struct.new(:search_terms, :state, :zipcode, :lat, :lon, :mile_radius, :account_type, :page, :page_size)

  #convert zipcode into lat, lon, and state
  def prepare
    zip = ZipCode.find(zipcode)
    self.lat = (lat.nil? ? zip.latitude : lat).to_f
    self.lon = (lon.nil? ? zip.longitude : lon).to_f
    self.state = (state.nil? ? zip.state : state).to_s
    self.mile_radius = (mile_radius.nil? ? '15' : mile_radius).to_i
    self.page_size = (page_size.nil? ? 50 : page_size).to_i
    self.page = (page.nil? ? 1 : page).to_i
    self.search_terms = (search_terms.nil? ? 'general' : search_terms).to_s
  end


end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many things here.

### Style considerations

First, in ruby [conditionals are expressions](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/12/21/lets-talk-about-conditional-expressions/), so instead of :

```
self.lat.nil? ? self.lat = zip.latitude.to_f : self.lat = self.lat.to_f
```

you can do :

```
self.lat = self.lat.nil? ? zip.latitude.to_f : self.lat.to_f
```

you can also get rid of `self` when not assigning :

```
self.lat = lat.nil? ? zip.latitude.to_f : lat.to_f
```

you can also group statements :

```
self.lat = (lat.nil? ? zip.latitude : lat).to_f
```

also, this is roughly equivalent to :

```
self.lat ||= zip_latitude
self.lat = lat.to_f
```

### Design considerations

Your controller is too fat. especially this :

```
  @conditions = ContractorSearchConditions.new()
  @conditions.zipcode = @service_request.zipcode.to_s
  @conditions.search_terms = params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:keywords].present? ? params[:filters][:keywords] : 'general'
  params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:proximity].present? ? @conditions.mile_radius = params[:filters][:proximity] :
  params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:results].present? ? @conditions.page_size = params[:filters][:results] :
  @conditions.page = 1
```

Basicly all of this should be in the body of `ContractorSearchConditions#initialize` method (give up the struct, use a real class : too much logic is attached to this entity to be a simple bag of data), so that you can do :

```
@conditions = ContractorSearchConditions.new( params[:search_conditions] )
```

**To be continued** I will come back when i have more time to analyze your logic, but here's a hint : when you have a lot of conditionals, it usually means you failed to capture a concept / mechanism as an object. Find out what concept(s) it is and you should be able to clean this.

**EDIT : Refactoring**

Let's analyze this bit of code :

```
  @conditions.search_terms = params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:keywords].present? ? params[:filters][:keywords] : 'general'
  params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:proximity].present? ? @conditions.mile_radius = params[:filters][:proximity] :
  params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:results].present? ? @conditions.page_size = params[:filters][:results] :
  @conditions.page = 1
```

first, we will use "real ifs" and proper indentation to see clear in this mess :

```
  if params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:keywords].present?
    @conditions.search_terms = params[:filters][:keywords]
  else 
    @conditions.search_terms = 'general' 
  end

  if params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:proximity].present?
    @conditions.mile_radius = params[:filters][:proximity]
  end

  if params[:filters].present? && params[:filters][:results].present?
    @conditions.page_size = params[:filters][:results]
  else
    @conditions.page = 1
  end
```

Still ugly, but more clear. Something important now stands out... Do you see it ?

```
  if params[:filters].present?

    # side note : here we use "presence" from ActiveSupport, 
    # which returns the object itself if it is not blank, or nil.
    @conditions.search_terms = params[:filters][:keywords].presence
    @conditions.mile_radius  = params[:filters][:proximity].presence 
    @conditions.page_size    = params[:filters][:results].presence

  end

  @conditions.search_terms ||= 'general'
  @conditions.page = 1 unless @condition.page_size
```

The whole logic has, in fact, **two purposes** :

- initialize the `@conditions` object using `params[:filters]`
- set default values if necessary

All of this should be the responsibility of `ContractorSearchConditions#initialize`.

```
class ContractorSearchConditions

  # here are defaults values, all contained in a constant.
  # Thanks to this, everyone that looks at that class knows
  # what to expect as default values with this object.
  #
  DEFAULTS = {
      search_terms: :general,
      page:         1,
      page_size:    50,  # those values are hard to find
      miles_radius: 15   # in the code you posted... not anymore !
  }.freeze

  def initialize( params = {} )
    # the magic happen here. We have default values, 
    # but let the caller override them :
    options = DEFAULTS.merge( params || {} ) 
    filters = options.delete( :filters ){ {} }

    assign_attributes( options )
    filters.each{|name, value| apply_filter( name, value )}
  end

  # use the attributes accessor to assign all values.
  # the benefit here is that each accessor encapsulates
  # rules about what is a valid value to assign, how to coerce it, etc.
  # one could also easily filter which attributes can be assigned this way,
  # à la "attr_accessible"
  #
  def assign_attributes( attributes )
    attributes.each{|attr,value| public_send "#{attr}=", value }
  end

  # example of custom writer with safety nets all over the place :
  # 
  def page=( value )
    return @page if value.blank?
    @page = value.to_i
  rescue NoMethodError 
    raise ArgumentError, "invalid value '#{value}' for page"
  end

  # we can do something somewhat similar with filters :
  #
  def apply_filter( name, value )
    public_send "#{name}_filter", value
  rescue NoMethodError
    raise ArgumentError, "unknown filter '#{name}'"
  end

  # example of filter :
  #
  def proximity_filter( value )
    self.mile_radius = value
    # this seems dumb, but would be really useful if you have complex behavior
    # like multiparameter filters, etc.  
  end

end
```

### What ? but this is far more complex !

yes... and no.

- This implementation provides **encapsulation** of data and behavior, and ensures that your object always initializes with default, sensible values, in a consistent state. This is the heart of OOP!
- This also means you won't have to repeat this code over and over if you need it in another controller : in other words, **reusability**.
- this is a lot of logic, but **you're doing many things** ! In fact, if you want this to be pure, outrageously OO code, you would have to create one object for each responsibility (SRP) :

  - extract parameters from a hash
  - map them to a set of attributes
  - coerce all values and guard against meaningless ones
  - etc.
- For now, you've stuffed a lot of logic in the controller. This works for small projects, but can quickly become a code swamp in bigger ones. The whole process you perform should have a dedicated place to live ! That's why many people (me included) would use some sort of `ContractorSearch` object that would represent... a search (duh) and that you would be able to manipulate like, say, an ActiveModel object. A (bit outdated) example of such approach can be seen in [railscasts #111](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form). This even allows you to easily save your searches !
- i admit i have a tendency to overengineer. My implementation may be too much, but you get the spirit...

Comment: First of all thank you!
I changed my method based on your comment.
I also added the view. Here is the behaviour. The user can access to the page and then apply filter if the default results are not good enough.
But I want to avoid logic in my view as much as possible, that's why I instantiate the params in the controller and I also want the inputs to be populated.

What do you think ?

Comment: i'm still editing my answer, I'll come back to you in a few minutes

Comment: wow, i may have gone over the board now. Sorry if its too long

Comment: as to your question, you should really see the [railscasts #11](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised) i linked in my answer.

Comment: one more word : with rails 3+, our `apply_filter` method can simply add scopes over a base relation. I usually have such a method, with 'optional' scopes that return an unchanged relation if a blank param is passed. This way you can chain them at will...

Comment: This is actually a pretty awesome answer!
I wish I could give more than one upvote!